# Managing permissions for users stored in mysql database

Tags: java, mysql, authentication, state

I have created a login form which queries a MySQL database to look for a combination of a username and password.
If there is not a match a dialog opens that sayys the combination is invalid. If there is a match the users get brought to a second screen that contains several buttons.....e.g. User Administration, View Tasks, etc.

The sql table for usernames and passwords has 5 columns, id, username, password, department, and user role. I want to be able to verify the identity based on user name and password and have certain buttons disabled based on their user role. i.e. administrator will have all buttons enabled, standard user will only have view tasks enabled and all other buttons disabled.

Also when the user clicks view tasks button I want the user to only view tasks associated with their department. After a user logs on I need a way to  hold the department and user the role of the user from the database and have impact the data displayed and available buttons across multiple forms.

I am not asking for the whole answer of how it should be coded but I have no idea how to keep track of these settings throughout my application.

Comment: One way to manage permissions is to have a UserPermission class that has boolean methods like isAdministrator and isUser.  Your GUI uses this class' methods to determine what JBUttons to enable.

Comment: So, logically after verifying credentials I would create the UserPermission class correct?

Comment: Yes, create an instance of the UserPermission class after verifying the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to maintain another table say 'MenuAsPerUserRole'. Here you would record the menus/buttons (titles) that can be accessible by the user with some roles.

Once, user log-ins, you would know his/her role and department. Store this information in session so that you can use it whenever required. That way, you would be able to query to database using the department and getting records only from that department.

For menus, query to the 'MenuAsPerUserRole' with the user role who has just logged in and display them in the UI.

I hope you get what you need.

Regards,

Comment: You say store this information in session. That is mostly what I am confused about, how is the information stored in a session? I know how to pull it from the database I just dont know where to store it so that it is accessible across the an instance of the entire application.

Comment: Have look at this :
https://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-5.5-doc/servletapi/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html